# Would a boat with another same sized hole in it take double the amount of time to fill or slightly less/more?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I read another similar question about a balloon draining water, but this question is different in the fact the water is filling the boat.
I was thinking it would take longer as there would be a bit of "confusion" in the water between two holes as it would need to "decide" which hole to enter. 
Excuse my lack of technical jargon, but I feel it is understandable.

Perhaps it would be to delineate the situation as the suction from the two holes would be competing for the same water which slow down the filling.

Comment: Would you please cite the older question? What you say is kinda meaningless without that context ;)

Answer (score 2):

The boat with two holes would fill in *half* the time (that is, *less* time).

The flow of liquid (in liters per second) through a hole depends on the pressure difference on the two sides, and the fluid resistance of the hole.  If the holes are at the same depth, then the pressure differences are the same for both holes.  If the holes are identical, their fluid resistances will be the same.  These are the only factors that affect the flow rate.  The holes don't "know" that there is another hole, nor does the water "know" that there are two holes and change its behavior.  Thus, the flow will be the same through each individual hole, and the two holes together have twice the flow as one.

Since the volume is the same in both cases, but the flow doubles with two holes, the boat with two holes will fill in half the time.

---

**Addendum:** Outside of science, people often explain how objects work by treating them like beings that can make decisions.  We call this [*anthropomorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism).  This question uses the words *decide*, *competing*, and *confusion*.  It's understandable that non-scientists use this type of reasoning, but it often leads to misunderstandings and false conclusions.

A better way to approach this (and future) problems is to think about the physical conditions, and how they cause something to happen.  In this case, there is a certain amount of pressure on the bottom side of each hole.  The top side of the hole has a different amount of pressure.  This means there is a pressure difference, and that is what causes the water to flow.

*Suction* is one way of thinking about pressure differences.  However, you will later find problems where there is a pressure difference, but the idea of suction doesn't make sense (e.g. osmosis).  You are therefore better off trying to think in terms of pressure differences than suction.

Another advantage of thinking in the way I have shown is that you can later generalize the problem.  It turns out that fluid flow and pressure differences can be quantified and form the basis for the Bernoulli equation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps it would be to delineate the situation as the suction from the two holes would be competing for the same water which slow down the filling.

Comment: @user209627 There's no real reason to even have suction on the holes.  To think of it another way, the water isn't being sucked into the boat; gravity is _pushing_ the boat into the water; which allows water to start to squeeze in.

Comment: (Of course, if one hole is initially above the water line the answer is different). Sorry, couldn't resist...

Comment: Perhaps suction isn't the best word either. Simplify it to the holes are competing for the same water.

Comment: @user209627 They aren't really "competing" for the water though.  The water doesn't really have to make a choice, because it's different water flowing into each hole.  If anything, it's more like the water is competing for the holes.  If there's more holes, there are more ways for the water to get in, therefore more of the water "competing" can get into the boat compared to a single hole that all the water has to try to go through at the same time.  It's like having two lines open instead of one at a cash register; since there's two people serving, lines should take half as long.

Comment: I made a small photo with 3-D paint.  https://ibb.co/e0Wkt0

Comment: @user209627 It would still be 2 different streams of water that could go in each hole.  I can't really imagine a scenario where 2 holes of the same size are slower than 1 of that same size.  Even if the flow into one hole caused a weird pressure gradient to make the second hole less effective, it should still be _better_ than having one hole on it's own.  In general, fluid flows better when there's less resistance, and more surface area to flow through (more holes) will be less resistance except for some very odd edge cases; as described, this doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: @JMac, the OP is not asking whether adding a second hole makes the boat sink more slowly that the one-hole case. He/she is asking whether whether the time to sink is _proportional_ to the number of holes or, more than proportional or, less than proportional. I.e., with two holes, will it sink in half the time? or more than half the time? or less than half the time?

Comment: @SolomonSlow My interpretation is that it's _exactly_ what they are asking.  The wording used and the responses given haven't really done anything to dispute that either.  They asked "_Would a boat with another same sized hole in it take double the amount of time to fill or slightly less/more?_" They asked if adding a second hole would _double_ the time it takes to fill, and then suggested that the water might get "confused".  If OP meant approximately _half_ the time, they should make that clear.  That misconception was brought up right away above and OP never remarked on it either way.

Comment: oops! Of course, I should have said, _inversely_ proportional...  In my head, I was thinking "rate", but my fingers typed "time".